# Ionic 2 Audio file generated with cordova-plugin-media is not recognized

Tags: android, cordova, audio, plugins

I'm having an issue with the cordova Media plugin, I followed all the steps to generate an audio file from a voice record, everything is working fine, the file is created but when I try to open it with an audio player on my device it doesn't play at all and I get a message telling me that the player doesn't handle this file type.

Here's the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { MediaPlugin, MediaObject} from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private isRecording: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private media: MediaPlugin, private file: File) {
  }

  record(){
    this.isRecording = true;
    const onStatusUpdate = (status) => console.log(status);
    const onSuccess = () => console.log('Action is successful.');
    const onError = (error) => console.error(error.message);

    const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('my_awesome_file.aac', onStatusUpdate, onSuccess, onError);

    file.startRecord();
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      file.stopRecord();
      file.release();
    }, 10000);
  }

  stop(){
    this.isRecording = false;
  }

  noRecording(){
    return !this.isRecording;
  }
}
```

For now I only start the recording by clicking on record and I set a timeout to make it stop after 10 seconds. In the console logs everything is going well, the action is successful and the file generated.

Could it be because of my device? I made it run on a samsung galaxy tab 3 running under android 4.4.2

Has someone already had had this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it comes from the device kitkat is too old, I made another test with a lollipop and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. Turns out my device was too old as well. I tried every single file extension (mp3, wav, aac, amr, m4a). Nothing worked - the phone would just keep saying that it couldn't play the file. Oddly enough, the media file had a duration of 0 seconds, but the media file had an actual file size (as in, bytes were actually recorded to it). I also logged the amplitude to the console, which fluctuated as I spoke into the microphone, which indicated it must have been picking up something. I was using version 5.0.1 ("Lollipop"), but when I switched over to 6.0.1("Marshmallow") it worked perfectly, even asked for device permissions before recording.

I also ran into the problem where a tmprecording was generated in the root of the sd card, I used this post to fix that:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/mediaplugin-does-not-save-audio-recording-into-file-ionic-native/91868/4

Also, you will need to create a unique file name for the recording as it doesn't seem to overwrite files? Need to do more testing on that.

Best of luck to anyone who sees this.